# Issues with virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

Having a bit of an issue with virtualenv. I've followed the steps in this tutuorial:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

And when I run virtualenv I get:

```
My-Maco:django-projects auser$ virtualenv test
Creating test/lib/python2.7
Creating test/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Creating test/bin
Copying /usr/bin/python to test/bin
Installing setuptools
python: posix_spawn: /Users/auser/Documents/django-projects/test/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

It's copying `python` to `test/bin`, so why is it looking for `test/bin/python2.7`?

Comment: How did you setup Python?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had incompatible versions of pip and virtualenv installed for my python version (2.7.5). I did the following to fix

```
sudo pip unistall pip
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

Notice that I installed pip via `easy_install` instead of `brew`